# can Eclipse display multiple Variable windows at a time?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse allows multiple source windows (obviously) and even multiple console windows to be open at the same time.

I'm looking to see if there is a way to open multiple Variable windows at a time.  While debugging I sometimes want to visually compare several structures and this would be easier if I could open each object in its own Variable window.

Thanks.

Comment: In Eclipse Kepler, I can't find the Open New View button any more, however you can type in expressions in the Expressions view and have it displayed along with the Variables view.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the upper right hand corner of the Variables window, there should be a button 'Open New View'.

[image]

**EDIT**: I'm not sure if this is necessarily the best way to get what you want, but it worked for me.  I just downloaded a fresh Kepler install, and you can get the "Open New View" button by installing the C/C++ Development Tools.  To install go to Help > Install New Software.

[image]

**Note**: I had to clean my workspace after installing because I was getting "Editor does not contain a main type errors".  But after that everything worked fine and the button was available.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't see that button when I have Variables selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with having two windows, which will have same debug instance connected, then there is a work around to achieve this. When you are debugging and is paused at a debug point, choose: **Window -> New Window**. Then another window gets opened. Let the new and old windows be side by side. Now in this newly opened window, choose: **Window -> Show View -> Debug**. Now you will get the same line of code opened at which the debug is paused in the old window. Now choose: **Window -> Show View -> Variables**. Now you get two Variable views which have the same instances of variables available. In my case, I wanted to compare old and new values present in one complicated object and it was easy when I could compare them side by side, rather than scrolling up and down in Variables view.